# Operator difference: +=, ==, +, ++, =

Tags: java, operators

I was learning how to use switch, but I used different operators and the program wouldn't run. Only `=` operator worked. Why do the other operators (`+=`, `==`, `+`, `++`) not work in this case?

I am a beginner in Java, please kindly help me with this naive question.

```
double shippingCost;

switch (shipping) {
  case "Regular":
    shippingCost + 0;
    break;
  case "Express":    
    shippingCost + 1.75;
    break;
  default:
    shippingCost + .50; 
}

return shippingCost;
```

Comment: Java doesn't let you make a statement out of just a value expression like `shippingCost + 0`. There's no point.

Comment: If you want to alter the value of `shippingCost`, you need to use `+=`. Otherwise, the result of the addition is lost.

Comment: Other issue: variable `shippingCost` is not initialized.

Comment: @CaiusJard I assumed that his goal was to alter the value of the variable, but of course, I can't be sure of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to learn about the usage of these operators. += operator is usually used when you want to sum and assignment task at the same time. For example, in the given code '+=' operator is used to add value to a variable and storing it in that variable in one go.

'==' operator is used for the comparison purposes, in this case switch automatically does it in the background.Like in our case, shipping variable is compared to different case statements.
'+' operator is just to sum some values. In your case, **you are just adding value to shippingCost variable but not storing it in any variable**. 
'++' operator is to increment the variable's value by 1.

The sample Code working for me is as below:
Two things to be corrected are to initialize shippingCost Variable with some value before using it in your code and to use += operator or + and = operator separately to add some value and assign it to the variable.
I hope, it may be helpful for you.

```
String shipping = "Regular"
double shippingCost=0;
switch (shipping) {
    case "Regular":
            shippingCost += 0;
            break;
    case "Express":    
            shippingCost += 1.75;
            break;
    default:
            shippingCost += .50; 
}
return shippingCost;
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re just making expressions right now, what you want to do is assign the expression to something.

To better understand the code

```
shippingCost + 1.75
```

Returns some value , what you want to do is assign it to something.

If you want the value to equal the value plus something, the correct syntax would be

```
variable += value
```

So in your example you would probably want

```
shippingCost += 1.75
```

If you want to use

```
==
```

You can think of as an expression that returns a Boolean, aka a true or false value. You can assign it to a variable the same way you can with any value. Or you can simply use the value.

Answer (score 0):

None of those additions are complete statements. I think your expectation is probably that shippingCost+1 etc would cause shippingCost to be increased by 1, but it doesn't - if it did it would make things very awkward just doing some basic maths:

```
print(productCost + packagingCost + shippingCost);
```

If performing a sum stored something back in the variable this would get messy very quickly; all these variables would increase every time they were printed

We have to be explicit about what we want to happen. If you want shippingCost to increase by one we have to calculate and store the result back:

```
shippingCost = shippingCost + 1;
```

Or use ++, which is defined to mean "increment the variable by one", or use += which is defined to mean "increase the variable on the left by the value on the right"

Here are other examples of complete statements:

```
shippingCost = 0;

shippingCost++;

shippingCost += 2;

if(shippingCost == 3)
  doSomething();
```

This is not a statement:

```
shippingCost + 1;
```

Unless you include something else that makes use of the value result like this:

```
shippingCost = shippingCost + 1;

double newShippingCost = shippingCost + 1;

print(shippingCost + 1);
```

It's not a legal complete statement in Java, to calculate a result and do nothing with it. The examples I gave that are complete statements do do something with the result; mostly they store the result (back) into the shippingCost variable. Starting out at 0, shopping cost was then incremented, then increments again and finally compared to the value 3 (which would have produced a true)

Comment: `do()` ? `do` is a keyword and can therefor not be used as a method name...

Comment: sorted, thanks @dan1st

Answer (score 0):

In Java 
+ operation result needs to be assigned to a target variable, for example

```
a = 1+2;
```

+= is a short hand for adding a value to one variable and assign the result to it self.

```
a += 5; // is equivalent to a=a+5;
```

== is only used for comparison, say

```
if(a==b) { //do something}
```

++ is for incrementing an number usually integer

```
int a=1;
a++; //is equivalent to a=a+1;    a=2 after running this statment.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Only `=` operator worked. Why do the other operators (`+=`, `==`, `+`, `++`) not work in this case?

The other operators will result in compilation errors, but for different reasons.

---

The operators `==` and `+` do a comparison or addition, resulting in a new value, without any side-effects. If you wrote `a + b;` as a statement then this statement would have no effect on what your program does; in theory it could add two numbers, but then **the result is not used for anything**, and hence the operation would effectively do nothing.

The compiler reports an error in these cases because you would not intentionally write code that does nothing, therefore the code must not do what you did intend, and the compiler tells you so.

---

The operators `+=` and `++` do have side-effects, but these give you compilation errors for a different reason. When you declare a local variable like `double shippingCost;` without an initial value, then you cannot use this variable in an expression until it is [definitely assigned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) by some other expression later.

That means if you wrote something like `System.out.println(shippingCost);` you'd get a compilation error because you're trying to print the value of a variable, but that variable does not yet have a value assigned to it, so there is no value that could be printed. Likewise, if you write `shippingCost += 1.75` or `shippingCost++` then you are trying to add something to the old value, but **there is no old value to be added to**. Hence there is a compilation error.